ROS2 MoveIt!2 "No acceleration limit was defined for joint! You have to define acceleration limits in the URDF or joint_limits.yaml"
Im trying to get a UR3e simulation running with MoveIt2 in RViz and Gazebo. I have the robot generating in RViz and Gazebo, and can move it around in RViz. When i try to plan a trajectory, i get the following error and no motion happens:
[move_group-10] [ERROR] [1712929712.748918500] [moveit_trajectory_processing.time_optimal_trajectory_generation]: No acceleration limit was defined for joint shoulder_pan_joint! You have to define acceleration limits in the URDF or joint_limits.yaml

I have the acceleration limits set to true in the joint_limits.yaml file, and have a max_acceleration value set.
Below i have included the launch file, error messages and a few other pieces of information that may be useful. Im using ROS Iron on Ubuntu 22.04. Been bashing my head against this for a couple of days so help would be appreaciated! Having to put GH links rather than code snippets as files are too long and hit the post character limit.
Launch File:
https://github.com/HR-ES/UR_ROS/blob/simulation/src/ur3e_moveit/launch/ur3e_action_interface.launch.py
Error Log:
https://github.com/HR-ES/UR_ROS/blob/simulation/ErrorLog_NoAccelLimit
joint_limits.yaml:
https://github.com/HR-ES/UR_ROS/blob/simulation/src/ur3e_moveit/config/joint_limits.yaml
ur3e_macro_urdf.xacro:
https://github.com/HR-ES/UR_ROS/blob/simulation/src/ur3e_gazebo_sim/urdf/ur3e_macro.urdf.xacro
ur3e.urdf.xacro:
https://github.com/HR-ES/UR_ROS/blob/simulation/src/ur3e_gazebo_sim/urdf/ur3e.urdf.xacro
ur3e_ros2_control.xacro:
https://github.com/HR-ES/UR_ROS/blob/simulation/src/ur3e_gazebo_sim/urdf/ur3e_ros2_control.xacro

Please accept the answer instead of commenting in the answer field from another account.

The names of the joints in joint_limits.yaml are incorrect. It should be shoulder_pan_joint not just shoulder_pan.
